Segfault when running thread in C program after converting from Python
I'm attempting to convert a Python script to C to improve its performance. The Python script involves threading, and I've translated it to C using an AI. However, when I compile and run the C script, I encounter a segmentation fault.
Python3 script
import threading, time

class creation_worker_thread:
      def A(starting_exec):
          running_list = []
          for step in range(1, workers_range + 1):
              running_list.append(generate_thread(create_threads, (starting_exec, 0)))
              starting_exec += per_worker
          start_thread_list(running_list)

      def B(starting_exec):
          running_list = []
          for step in range(1, workers_range + 1):
              running_list.append(generate_thread(create_threads, (starting_exec, 1)))
              starting_exec += per_worker
          start_thread_list(running_list)

      def C(starting_exec):
          running_list = []
          for step in range(1, workers_range + 1):
              running_list.append(generate_thread(create_threads, (starting_exec, 2)))
              starting_exec += per_worker
          start_thread_list(running_list)

      def D(starting_exec):
          running_list = []
          for step in range(1, workers_range + 1):
              running_list.append(generate_thread(create_threads, (starting_exec, 3)))
              starting_exec += per_worker
          start_thread_list(running_list)

class execution_worker_thread:
      def A(starting_exec):
          running_list = []
          for step in range(1, workers_range + 1):
              running_list.append(generate_thread(exec_threads, (starting_exec, 0)))
              starting_exec += per_worker
          start_thread_list(running_list)

      def B(starting_exec):
          running_list = []
          for step in range(1, workers_range + 1):
              running_list.append(generate_thread(exec_threads, (starting_exec, 1)))
              starting_exec += per_worker
          start_thread_list(running_list)

      def C(starting_exec):
          running_list = []
          for step in range(1, workers_range + 1):
              running_list.append(generate_thread(exec_threads, (starting_exec, 2)))
              starting_exec += per_worker
          start_thread_list(running_list)

      def D(starting_exec):
          running_list = []
          for step in range(1, workers_range + 1):
              running_list.append(generate_thread(exec_threads, (starting_exec, 3)))
              starting_exec += per_worker
          start_thread_list(running_list)

def main_program(value):
    return

def generate_thread(function, argument):
    return threading.Thread(target=function, args=(argument,))

def start_thread_list(list):
    for thread in list:
        thread.start()
    for thread in list:
        thread.join()

def exec_threads(argument):
    counter = 1
    for thread in created_threads_list[argument[1]][argument[0]:]:
        thread.start()
        if counter >= per_worker:
           break
        counter += 1

def create_threads(argument):
    counter = 1
    for value in request_file[argument[0]:]:
        created_threads_list[argument[1]].append(generate_thread(main_program, value))
        if counter == per_worker:
           break
        counter += 1

def thread_workers(argument):
    creation_workers_list[argument[0]](argument[1])
    execution_workers_list[argument[0]](0)
    return created_threads_list[argument[0]].clear()

def exec_workers():
    starting_exec, list = 0, []
    for current_worker in range(max_workers):
        list.append(generate_thread(thread_workers, (current_worker, starting_exec)))
        starting_exec += per_worker * workers_range
    start_thread_list(list)

def end_timer(start_time):
    run_time = "{:.2f}".format(time.time() - start_time)
    return print(f"Runtime: {run_time} seconds")

def start_multi_threading(argument):
    start_time = time.time()
    return exec_workers(), end_timer(start_time)

def share_work_load(file_length):
    answer = max_workers - (file_length % max_workers)
    if answer == max_workers:
       answer = 0
    request_file.extend([0] * answer)
    file_length = len(request_file)
    per_worker = file_length // max_workers
    max_per = per_worker
    while per_worker >= 256:
          per_worker //= 2
    workers_range = max_per // per_worker
    return workers_range, per_worker, file_length - (workers_range * per_worker * max_workers)

def generate_request(testing):
    requests , max = [], 4096
    if testing:
       for integer in range(1, max + 1):
           requests.append(integer)
       return requests
    with open('/root/lists/list.txt', 'r') as file:
         return file.readlines()

testing = True
request_file = generate_request(testing)
max_workers, created_threads_list = 4, [[], [], [], []]
workers_range, per_worker, remainder = share_work_load(len(request_file))
creation_workers_list = [creation_worker_thread.A, creation_worker_thread.B,
                         creation_worker_thread.C, creation_worker_thread.D]
execution_workers_list = [execution_worker_thread.A, execution_worker_thread.B,
                          execution_worker_thread.C, execution_worker_thread.D]
print(workers_range, per_worker, remainder)
start_multi_threading(print('\n\033[93mrunning...\033[0m'))

C code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_WORKERS 4
#define MAX_PER_WORKER 256

int per_worker;
int workers_range;
int remaining; // Renamed variable to avoid conflict
int request_file[4096]; // Assuming a maximum size for the request file
pthread_t created_threads_list[MAX_WORKERS][MAX_PER_WORKER];

void* main_program(void* arg) {
    // Main program logic here
    return NULL;
}

void* create_threads(void* arg) {
    int worker_id = *((int*)arg);
    int starting_exec = worker_id * workers_range * per_worker;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = starting_exec; i < starting_exec + per_worker; i++) {
        if (i >= sizeof(request_file) / sizeof(request_file[0])) {
            break;
        }
        pthread_create(&created_threads_list[worker_id][counter], NULL, main_program, &request_file[i]);
        counter++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void* exec_threads(void* arg) {
    // Similar logic to create_threads, adjust as needed
    return NULL;
}

void start_thread_list(pthread_t* list, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        pthread_join(list[i], NULL);
    }
}

void exec_workers() {
    pthread_t thread_list[MAX_WORKERS];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_WORKERS; i++) {
        pthread_create(&thread_list[i], NULL, create_threads, &i);
    }
    start_thread_list(thread_list, MAX_WORKERS);
}

void* thread_workers(void* arg) {
    int worker_id = *((int*)arg);
    create_threads(&worker_id);
    exec_threads(&worker_id);
    // Clearing created threads list
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PER_WORKER; i++) {
        pthread_cancel(created_threads_list[worker_id][i]);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void share_work_load(int file_length) {
    remaining = file_length % MAX_WORKERS;
    if (remaining == MAX_WORKERS) {
        remaining = 0;
    }
    // Adjust file length to fit evenly across workers
    file_length += remaining;
    per_worker = file_length / MAX_WORKERS;
    int max_per = per_worker;
    while (per_worker >= 256) {
        per_worker /= 2;
    }
    workers_range = max_per / per_worker;
}

void generate_request(int testing) {
    int max = 4096;
    if (testing) {
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            request_file[i] = i + 1;
        }
    } else {
        FILE* file = fopen("/root/lists/list.txt", "r");
        if (file == NULL) {
            perror("Error opening file");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        char line[256];
        int i = 0;
        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
            request_file[i++] = atoi(line);
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
}

void start_quantum_threading() {
    generate_request(1); // Set to 1 for testing
    share_work_load(sizeof(request_file) / sizeof(request_file[0]));
    pthread_t thread_list[MAX_WORKERS];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_WORKERS; i++) {
        pthread_create(&thread_list[i], NULL, thread_workers, &i);
    }
    start_thread_list(thread_list, MAX_WORKERS);
}

int main() {
    start_quantum_threading();
    return 0;
}

And here's the error message:
zsh: segmentation fault  ./compiled_script

I suspect the issue might be related to memory management or thread creation.
How can I resolve this segmentation fault error?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Edit
I complied the c code using the flags -fsanitize=address -pthread and got the below output
AddressSanitizer: CHECK failed: sanitizer_allocator_primary64.h:131 "((kSpaceBeg)) == ((address_range.Init(TotalSpaceSize, PrimaryAllocatorName, kSpaceBeg)))" (0x600000000000, 0xfffffffffffffff4) (tid=3560)
    <empty stack>


Apart from anything else you're passing the same address of the local loop index &i to all copies of thread_workers.  So possibly a dangling pointer and, even if not, there's a distinct probability multiple copies of thread_workers will end up using the same value of i.  Please learn to use a debugger and stop relying on the results of generative AI.

@G.M. I appreciate your explanation. As I'm relatively new to C programming, could you please provide a full copy of the corrected working C script? It would be immensely helpful for me to understand the changes needed to resolve the segmentation fault issue.

Running a build compiled with -fsanitize=address helps identify such issues,

Aside: double-spacing the code makes it hard to read.

You did not demonstrate your problem since what you provided isn't runnable due to missing files.

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) You do not check that you don't read more than 4096 lines which would cause overflow of request_file

Isn't // Assuming a maximum size for the request file easy to follow up (or eliminate as a reason)? It's an obvious danger.

@ikegami I added -fsanitize=address to the 9th line in the c script and when compling the code I got the below output

script.c: In function ‘create_threads’: script.c:23:53: error: ‘per_worker’ undeclared (first use in this function)    23 |     int starting_exec = worker_id * workers_range * per_worker;

script.c:23:53: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in script.c: In function ‘share_work_load’: script.c:72:5: error: ‘per_worker’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘exec_workers’?

72 |     per_worker = file_length / MAX_WORKERS;       |     ^~~~~~~~~~       |     exec_workers Compilation failed.

Those errors have nothing to do with -fsanitize=address. You provided bad code. And different code than what you posted at that. /// Please address the issue raised in my second comment.

just for curiosity: running ./compiled_script (compiled C source generated by cython from script.py) doesn't show any improvements comparing to python script.py: the same runtime ~0.4 seconds in my env

also for all our clarity, please edit your question and add any relevant error output there, instead of buried in the span of 3 comments.

I know it's the same run time that's why I decide to use pure c code. The above c code wasn't generated useing cython

@ikegami edit the c code and remove the 9th line I added earlier and complied the code use the flags -fsanitize=address -pthread and got the output AddressSanitizer: CHECK failed: sanitizer_allocator_primary64.h:131 "((kSpaceBeg)) == ((address_range.Init(TotalSpaceSize, PrimaryAllocatorName, kSpaceBeg)))" (0x600000000000, 0xfffffffffffffff4) (tid=3560)     <empty stack>

@Æmmy change line 59 to pthread_t thr = created_threads_list[worker_id][i]; if (thr) pthread_cancel(thr); due to conditional pthread_create() in line 28


I have no idea what that particular message means. 2) Still waiting for a runnable demonstration. This is the third time I've requested this. 3) Are you saying you don't enable your compiler's warnings? ouch!


@yvs2014 Thanks, the code now runs without any errors. The only issue am having is that it only executes  main_program 384 times instead of 4096

I'm just looking at the C code. Why does exec_workers create MAX_WORKER threads that invoke create_threads to generate per_worker subthreads??? exec_workers should just call create_threads (not use pthread_create). I've done many such "split up file processing amongst N worker threads" programs before. The generated code is horrible. Sorry, but I'd toss it completely. And, to be frank, I'm not sure this is just the translation. The python code looks convoluted.

@Æmmy that code creates 4 pools with 128 workers. Taking into account some explicit race condition in their creation, you got 3 pools by 128, i.e. 384, i.e. math is correct.

For some examples, please see my answers: Why my multi-thread program runs slower than single thread? and Why does my program work fine without threads but behaves unexpectedly when adding threads? and In C, is storing data in local variables in threads akin to creating a local copy? AKA Does this Threadpool synchronization make sense?
